# Values of an array showing wrong values

Tags: php

I'm trying to use files to set the language.

```
$_LANG[000] = 'Inicío';
$_LANG[001] = 'Principal';
$_LANG[002] = 'Procurar';
$_LANG[003] = 'Estatísticas';
$_LANG[004] = 'Calendário';
$_LANG[005] = 'Pagamentos';
$_LANG[006] = 'Finanças';
$_LANG[007] = 'Gestão';
$_LANG[008] = 'Administração';
$_LANG[009] = 'Boleto Bancário';
$_LANG[010] = 'Cartão de Crédito';
$_LANG[011] = 'Boleto';
$_LANG[012] = 'Visa';
$_LANG[013] = 'MasterCard';
$_LANG[014] = 'HiperCard';
$_LANG[015] = 'Diners Club';
$_LANG[016] = 'American Express';
$_LANG[017] = 'Itaú';
$_LANG[018] = 'Caixa';
$_LANG[019] = 'Bradesco';
$_LANG[020] = 'Banrisul';
$_LANG[021] = 'Visan Eletron';
$_LANG[022] = 'Débido';
$_LANG[023] = 'Crédito';
$_LANG[024] = 'Check In';
$_LANG[025] = 'Check Out';
$_LANG[026] = 'Verificar';
$_LANG[027] = 'Verificando';
$_LANG[028] = 'Fatura';
$_LANG[029] = 'Módulos';
$_LANG[030] = 'Notas Escolares';
$_LANG[031] = 'Faltas';
$_LANG[032] = 'Ano Létivo';
$_LANG[033] = 'Desempenho Escolar';
$_LANG[034] = 'Sumário';
$_LANG[035] = 'Cadastrar Usuário';
$_LANG[036] = 'Novo Usuário';
$_LANG[037] = 'Erro 404';
$_LANG[038] = 'Página Não Dísponivel';
$_LANG[039] = 'Página Não Encontrada';
$_LANG[040] = 'Galeria';
$_LANG[041] = 'Perfil';
$_LANG[042] = 'Configuração';
$_LANG[043] = 'Configurações';
$_LANG[044] = 'Mudar Senha';
$_LANG[045] = 'Sair';
$_LANG[046] = 'Encerrar';
$_LANG[047] = 'Sessão';
$_LANG[048] = 'Mensagens';
$_LANG[049] = 'Notificações';
$_LANG[050] = 'Ver todas notificações';
$_LANG[051] = 'Ver todas mensagens';
$_LANG[052] = 'Ver notificações';
$_LANG[053] = 'Ver mensagem';
$_LANG[054] = 'Aprovado';
$_LANG[055] = 'Reprovado';
$_LANG[056] = 'Recuperação';
$_LANG[057] = '1ª';
$_LANG[058] = '2ª';
$_LANG[059] = '3ª';
$_LANG[060] = '4ª';
$_LANG[061] = '5ª';
$_LANG[062] = '6ª';
$_LANG[063] = '1º';
$_LANG[064] = '2º';
$_LANG[065] = '3º';
$_LANG[066] = '4º';
$_LANG[067] = '5º';
$_LANG[068] = '6º';
$_LANG[069] = 'Chamada';
$_LANG[070] = 'Declaração';
$_LANG[071] = 'Escolar';
$_LANG[072] = 'Transfêrencia';
$_LANG[073] = 'Notícia';
$_LANG[074] = 'Notícias';
$_LANG[075] = 'Acadêmico';
$_LANG[076] = 'Ideias';
$_LANG[077] = 'Ajuda';
$_LANG[078] = 'Suporte Técnico';
$_LANG[079] = 'Relatório';
$_LANG[080] = 'Horários';
$_LANG[081] = 'Quadro de Horários';
$_LANG[082] = 'Notas / Faltas';
$_LANG[083] = 'Plano Ensino';
$_LANG[084] = 'Imprimir';
$_LANG[085] = 'Financeira';
$_LANG[086] = 'Word';
$_LANG[087] = 'Exel';
$_LANG[088] = 'PowerPoint';
$_LANG[089] = 'Skype';
$_LANG[090] = 'Outlook';
$_LANG[091] = 'E-mail';
$_LANG[092] = 'Dúvidas';
$_LANG[093] = 'Bimestre';
$_LANG[094] = 'Semestre';
```

then I want showing "Inicío" for that I need to insert `print $ _LANG [000];`

the problem is that it shows the right value
only starting from 010
I do not know why

Comment: you need to enclose any thing starting with a 0 `$ _LANG ['010']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're prefixing the keys with `0`, so they're being treated as octal numbers.

e.g.

```
$_LANG[027(octal)] is actually $_LANG[23(decimal)
$_LANG[010(octal)] is actually $_LANG[8(decimal)]
```

Either use strings:

```
$_LANG['027']
```

or normal decimals:

```
$_LANG[27]
```

Comment: Someone's got a `str_replace` to do and/or `regex`.